# NextJS putting redux in a component not in Pages but in a hoc layout

Tags: react-redux, next.js

Trying to get redux working in my Navbar which is placed in my Layout higher ordered component.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Navbar);
```

at the bottom of my Navbar.js is giving me this error

> Could not find "store" in either the context or props of
>   "Connect(navbarItems)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(Navbar)".

and I cannot configure redux in my layout or I get this error

```
Attention, withRedux has to be used only for top level pages, all other components must be wrapped with React Red
ux connect!
```

Comment: How and where do you initialize the store? Did you checked https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-higher-order-component ? It is redux is with HOC

Comment: using withRedux you should wrap only the component inside /pages which are top level pages, take a look at this example to see how the store is created and passed to the components: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux